# Universal width when using freeform

Tags: ios, xcode, view, freeform

I used the freeform option on my scrollview and parent view so that I can use the storyboard builder to add labels and textfields. Now I am having trouble getting everything entered horizontally when simulating. It's different on every device.

I enabled the auto-layout option, and size classes. Also I have added the constraint for horizontal alignment on each object inside the scroll controller. The last screenshot is from the simulator. As you can see; the width of the freeform view is too large. I can scroll horizontally and vertically. The first one (horizontal scrolling) should not exist.

[image: The view]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should deactivate **Use Size Classes**

Open StoryBoard and select your Controller. On the right side select the first Icon (Show the File Inspector) and then deactivate **Use Size Classes**

*Not realy sure but I would also change Freeform to Fixed Size*

Comment: That means I have to chose between iPhone and iPad. But I want to use both devices.

Comment: @user2014780 in your Project Settings (General -> Deployment Info) select Devices : Universal